# Elasticsearch curator in windows?

Tags: elasticsearch-curator

I have installed elasticsearch curator in my windows machine by default the location will be in `C:\Users\username` based on [ESdoc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/command-line.html).
But i didn't find any .curator files in that location?

May i know where it is stored?
Do i need python to execute curator?

Answer (score 3):

Curator does not install any default files for you.  You must build your own.  You can create a curator.yml based on the [example in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/configfile.html).  You can install this at `C:\Users\username\.curator\curator.yml` to have it be automatically picked up when you execute Curator.

Action files can also be created based on the [examples in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/examples.html).

If you installed from the [Windows Binary Zip package](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/windows-zip.html) or the [Windows MSI Installer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/windows-msi.html) for Curator, you do not need Python as it is bundled with those packages.

Comment: After setting up curator.yml to delete indices; how to start it to work forever like a windows service? For example, if I want to delete my indices older than 30 days; should I trigger the curator every month?

Comment: Typically, you would use some service, like the Task Scheduler for this.

Comment: Then what is the point to use curator? We can run a delete indicies command on elasticSearch directly with powershell and taskscheduler. I am confused.

Comment: Curator is an index selection wrapper around common APIs.  If you're only doing deletes, then perhaps that works for you, which is fine.  Curator is helpful for scheduling snapshots, index closures, forcemerges, and several other APIs, some of which are harder to select for than just deletes.